# dynamic div height attribute

Tags: css

I'm looking to extend the height of my div dynamically with my menu on the left. Here is the url:
http://www.whiterootmedia.com

I would like to add grass and the bass of the tree to the bottom of this web page. Any help or ideas?

currently the div has this inline css:

```
<div id="tree_trunk_div"style="position:relative;top:-100px; width:270px; text-align:right; margin-left:auto; background-image:url('../images/treetrunk7.png');background-repeat:repeat-y;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to do it ^^
http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

Almost... just a few tweaks.

```
<div id="tree_trunk_div" style="position:absolute;bottom:0px; width:270px; height:100%; text-align:right; margin-left:auto; background-image:url('../images/treetrunk7.png');background-repeat:repeat-y;">
```

Comment: Add a whitespace between `<div id="tree_trunk_div"` and `style="position:...`

Comment: @RobW don't think it makes a difference but I added it.

Comment: I tried this:`position:absolute;bottom:0px; right:0px; width:270px; height:100%;text-align:right; margin-left:auto; background-image:url('images/treetrunk7.png');background-repeat:repeat-y;` and it didn't work

Comment: @DustyArlia looks right to me... what doesn't work when you try it?

Comment: The background tree image didn't expand with the the menu on the left. I also added the the `right:0px` to keep it on the right side. But the problem with absolute is that when the screen width is made smaller the tree doesn't get properly pushed off the screen.

Comment: @DustyArlia Well, I'm running dry on ideas... in general you want both an in flow element and have it right aligned... and out of flow in that it is to the right until resized. I would say it might need javascript to work.

Comment: I don't think I can use absolute. I'm playing with `height:100%` but the parent div height is not set, but instead dynamically growing... so a little confused right now.

Comment: @DustyArlia Yeah, you could get most of the functionality you're looking for by changing my above code to `position:fixed;` and that would take care of that, but it wouldn't fix the fact that when you resize, it overlaps the content.  That would take js.

Comment: ... I couldn't overlook the resizing issues with `position:fixed`